# Long-term (6-8 hour) temperature monitoring for large renders

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature, monitoring

My question has to do with CPU and GPU overheating. I am starting to do some long animation renders (about 8 hours or so). I don't have any problems with figuring out how to monitor my temperatures. I use CPUID HW Monitor and I know of some other ones like openhardwaremonitor.org and aida64.com.

Most people do long renders while they are sleeping which makes these real time monitoring programs kind of pointless. I want to be able to look at a graph over time of my temperatures to make sure that over the course of a 8 hour render my CPU or GPU temps were fine. Any suggestions out there? I built my own computer and it was my first time so I want to keep my components in really good condition.

Thanks in advance and thanks for the time!

Tyler

Comment: So you're looking for a utility that will record temperature at given intervals and log these?

Comment: Please see the linked question. The accepted answer shows how enable logging on a respected tool.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks so much for the help!  Sorry for the duplicate.  I actually saw that question but didn't understand the technical jargon of logging to a file cause I'm a newbie